# Display Question OP username in 10-k tools

Tags: feature-request, questions, 10k-tools, display-names

I am working on some review tasks right now, checking "not an answer" flags, etc. [Sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005314/catching-a-soapexception-thrown-by-a-webservice/5029596#5029596), I notice that the flagged answer seems to be written by the OP themselves. Ideally, I'd want to verify this, so that I could leave a helpful comment to the OP, likely to the FAQ on the definition of an answer. However, in order to do so, I find that I need to navigate to the actual question to verify that the non-answer-poster and the OP are the same person. It seems that there's no indication of the username of the OP on the question, which is also displayed in this view.

I think it would be worthwhile to display the OP's username in the question in the 10-k tools view.